# FluentAutomation and finding element siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium

I have an application with a master/detail table where clicking in a cell expands a hidden row below the row the cell is in. I want to automate testing of this functionality using FA and Selenium. I have accomplished this using just Selenium but want to see if I can use the simplicity of FA.
I need to check that the detail row, the newly expanded one, contains the data retrieved by an ajax call so after it is expanded I need to find the actual next tr to assure that the data is there. I can't check just any, or all of the other rows, because it is possible the data is the same for more that one clicked cell / expanded row combination.

Is there a way to get the cell's parent (row) and then the next sibling of that parent using FA?

I tried mixing the two libraries in my app but Selenium Find returns IWebElements and FA Find returns IElements and they are not compatible so casting back and forth is not possible and neither one exposes anything useful as far as I can see.

As always your help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can find siblings through XPath. Show us what you are attempting to do, using code.

Comment: FluentAutomation's Find method returns Func<IElement> which can be cast to FluentAutomation.Element and exposes the underlying WebElement from Selenium, for situations where you need to access core Se functions.

Answer (score 1):

FleuentAutomation use Jquery to get element,which means that all jquery selector syntax can be applied in FluentAutomation. If you can get the count of element U can use

```
I.Find("td:parent")
```

then u can get its parent node. Then use

```
var count=I.FindMutiple("tr#id>td").Elements.Count;
```

then can get the count of children
Then can use

```
I.Find("td:eq("+i+")")
```

to go through all children.